# ForEach Async with limitations on amount of concurrent tasks that can run?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a well-known, well-tested nuget package that will provide me with a Parallel ForEach like capability, but where I can limit the amount of concurrent tasks that run at the same time?

I know I can write one myself, so not asking for code samples - just asking if there's a *popular* nuget package that would do that for me.

Thanks!

Comment: But Parallel.ForEach already has this capability built in via ParallelOptions.

Comment: But it's not async.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this gives you control over the degree of parallelism:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 50);
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };
Parallel.ForEach(items, parallelOptions,
    i =>
    {
        Task.Delay(1000).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // It's just an example 
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} I'm {i}");
    });
```

If you put `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` at 1, you will see that each item is processed sequentially.

From MSDN: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` Gets or sets the maximum number of concurrent tasks enabled by this ParallelOptions instance.

[Parallel.ForEach reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ParallelOptions reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This blocks the threads while IO is happening - I have a bunch of ASYNC code I want to run - no reason to block the thread.